# Find the limiting joint distribution of $X_n$ and $X_{n-1}$ as $n \to \infty$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, recurrence-relations, probability-limit-theorems

Let $Z_n \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and
$$
X_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2} X_n - \frac{5}{16} X_{n-1} + Z_n.
$$

Find the limiting joint distribution of $X_n$ and $X_{n-1}$ as $n \to \infty$.

**Attempt**

My approach was to rewrite the system as the one-lag system
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix} X_{n+1} \\ X_n \end{pmatrix}
&= \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{5}{16} \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix} X_n \\ X_{n-1} \end{bmatrix} +
 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} Z_n \\
&=: A
 \begin{bmatrix} X_n \\ X_{n-1} \end{bmatrix} +
 B Z_n
\end{align*} 
and solve for the covariance using the formula
$$
C = \sum_{k=0}^\infty A^k BB^t (A^k)^t.
$$
However, I don't know if this is the most reasonable way to solve for the covariance. It's quite easy to plug into MATLAB and evaluate the series but I wonder how to solve for $C$ without resorting to numerical methods.

Comment: don't we need to know the distributions of $X_0$ and $X_1$?